# I made an oath to god and i know i cant resist and not to break it

Tags: oaths

Hello my mom was sick 2 days ago and sense i love her so much i said to god if she make it out alive i will never masterbait again but i know i cant resist and if i break it at some case what should i do?

(By the way i am 14 years old and i dont know anything about any relgion i know there is a god exist but there is so much religons and its hard for me to choose i think i will probably be a muslim but im not sure )

Answer (score 0):

If you had made the oath in the name of Allah, you would have to do 3 fasts consecutively.

https://quran.com/5/89

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, the verse that was given by fahabccs.

"ALLAAH will not impose blame upon you for what is meaningless in your oaths, but He will impose blame upon you for what you intended of oaths. So its expiation is the feeding of ten needy people from the average of that which you feed your families or clothing them or the freeing of a slave. But whoever cannot find - then a fast of three days. That is the expiation for oaths when you have sworn. But guard your oaths. Thus does ALLAAH make clear to you His verses that you may be grateful."